# Разрешить ссылки в htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, htmlspecialchars

Нужно разрешить ссылки в htmlspecialchars, но не все, а начинающиеся с /, например, /upload/1.png

Есть функция

```
$pureHTML = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_NOQUOTES);
preg_match_all('/(&lt;\s*a)\s*(\w+="[\w:\/@#%_\-&\.]+")\s*(&gt;)/i', $pureHTML, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $pureHTML = str_replace($match[0], "<a " . $match[2] . ">", $pureHTML);
}
$pureHTML = preg_replace('/(&lt;\/\s*a\s*&gt;)/i', '</a>', $pureHTML);
```

В регулярках не шарю, как подправить? и безопасна ли данная функция?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй эту

```
/\/(\w+|\d+|\.)/ig
```

Здесь проверяй [RegExrv2.1](http://www.regexr.com/)